# Blog matching query does not exist. (%3Fid=)

Tags: python, django

Used `reverse()` in the model's method `get_absolute_url()`, but django raises an error - **DoesNotExist  at /blog/detail/?id=23**, becouse return not `correct url - "/%3Fid=23"` and urlpatterns haven't this in patterns, when I need the `correct url - "/?id=23"`. Why this happens and how to fix it?

[image]

**urls.py (blog app)**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
from blog.views import BlogListView, BlogDetailView, BlogCreate, BlogUpdate, BlogDelete

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', BlogListView.as_view(), name  = "blog"),
    url(r'^detail/(?:\?id=(?P<blog_id>\d+))?$', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name  = "blog_detail"),
    url(r'^add/(?:\?id=(?P<blog_id>\d+))?$', permission_required("blog.add_blog")(BlogCreate.as_view()), name  = "blog_add"),
    url(r'^edit/(?:\?id=(?P<blog_id>\d+))?$', permission_required("blog.change_blog")(BlogUpdate.as_view()), name  = "blog_edit"),
    url(r'^delete/(?:\?id=(?P<blog_id>\d+))?$', permission_required("blog.delete_blog")(BlogDelete.as_view()), name  = "blog_delete"),
]
```

**models.py (blog app)**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django_comments.moderation import CommentModerator, moderator
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Create your models here.

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique_for_date = "posted", verbose_name = "Title")
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name = "Description")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name = "Content")
    posted = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now(), db_index = True, verbose_name = "Posted")
    is_commentable = models.BooleanField(default = True, verbose_name = "Comments are allowed")
    tags = TaggableManager(blank = True, verbose_name = "Tags")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable = False)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog_detail", kwargs = {"blog_id": self.pk})
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-posted"]
        verbose_name = "blog article"
        verbose_name_plural = "blog articles"
```

**views.py** (blog app/only BlogCreate, BlogDetailView + e.t.c)

```
...

class PageNumberView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.sort = request.GET.get("sort")
        except KeyError:
            self.sort = "0"
        try:
            self.order = request.GET.get("order")
        except KeyError:
            self.order = "A"
        try:
            self.search = self.request.GET.get("search")
        except KeyError:
            self.search = ""
        try:
            self.tag = self.request.GET.get("tag")
        except KeyError:
            self.tag = ""
        return super(PageNumberView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            pn = self.request.GET.get("page", default=None)
            if pn == None:
                pn = "1"
        except KeyError:
            pn = "1"
        self.success_url = self.success_url + "?page=" + pn
        try:
            self.success_url = self.success_url + "&search=" + self.request.GET.get("search")
        except KeyError:
            pass
        try:
            self.success_url = self.success_url + "&tag=" + self.request.GET.get("tag")
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return super(PageNumberView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)


class PageNumberMixin(CategoryListMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageNumberMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context["pn"] = self.request.GET.get("page", default=None)
            if context["pn"] == None:
                context["pn"] = "1"
        except KeyError:
            context["pn"] = "1"
        return context

class BlogDetailView(PageNumberView, DetailView, SearchMixin, PageNumberMixin):
    model = Blog
    template_name = "blog_detail.html"
    def get_object(self):
        return self.model.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get('id'))

class CategoryListMixin(ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryListMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["current_url"] = self.request.path
        context["categories"] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

class BlogCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView, CategoryListMixin):
    model = Blog
    template_name = "blog_add.html"
    success_message = "Article successfully created"
    fields = '__all__'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(BlogCreate, self).form_valid(form)

...
```

Comment: You haven't shared what your `BlogDetailView` view looks like.

Comment: Why have you written your URLs like that? That's not how you write URLs in Django. Take all that `?:\?id=` stuff out.

Comment: The solution is to override the get_absolute_url() method with the following code, and remove the description of the GET format in the urlpatterns:

    def get_absolute_url (self):
        return '{}? {}'. format (reverse ("blog_detail"), urlencode ({'id': self.pk}))
    
    urlpatterns = [
        url (r '^ detail / $', BlogDetailView.as_view (), name = "blog_detail"),
    ]

Suggested a ready solution http://vk.com/timofey.kukushkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url pattern definition should be

```
url(r'^detail/$', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name="blog_detail"),
```

if you want to use GET parameters (query parameters) as in `/blog/detail/?blog_id=123`. The parameter can be accessed in the view with

```
blog_id = request.GET.get('blog_id')
blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
```

something like that.

Or if you want to make the `blog_id` part of your URL, the URL pattern must be

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name="blog_detail"),
```

In which case your URL will look like `/blog/detail/123/` and the value is available for access as a keyword argument.

Answer (score 1):

You just write url like this:

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name  = "blog_detail"),
```